# Passing ffmpeg options to a bash function

Tags: scripting, ffmpeg

Am writing a bash script where I can supply parameters for `ffmpeg`.  What would be a good way to pass the parameters to the function?  Using a string perhaps.

```
script.sh "-aq 1" *.mp4
```

One solution could involve detecting for files and directories, considering previous positional arguments- as parameters to `ffmpeg`.

Currently I am using a loop calling `ffmpeg` for each file.  Perhaps there is some way to pass all the files together no a single ffmpeg call as well?

Thus

```
  while (( $# > 0 )); do
   case $1 in
     ("--") shift 1 ; break ;;
     (*) if [[ ! -f "$1" ]]; then
           avopt+=("$1")
           shift 1 
         else
           break
         fi
         ;;
   esac
  done

  for fl in "$@"; do
    ffmpeg -i "$fl" -vn -acodec libvorbis ${avopt[@]} "$fl.ogg"
  done
```

Comment: In your example, what do you want are the parameters you want to pass to `ffmpeg`. Do you want to pass only the two arguments `-aq` and `1`, or the single string `-aq 1`, or do you also want to pass the expansion of the `*.mp4` filename glob (a list of filenames)?

Comment: I can have the script handle each possible option for ffmpeg, but think that would be an overkill.  Perhaps I can do `script.sh -aq 1 -- *.mp4`.   Alternatively I can check the positional arguments until I detect the first filename or directory name.

Comment: So you want to pass `-aq` and `1` to `ffmpeg`, but not the list of filenames?  Sorry, but your comment was not clear on that point. Maybe it would be better if you could give a full example of what you want in the question?

Comment: So, it seems as if you want to call `ffmpeg` with the given options and some extra options, and you want to do that for each of the given filenames, separately?

Comment: Correct.  Or can one do this in a single command?

Comment: Someone that knows `ffmpeg` may be able to answer that, if it's added as part of the question.

Comment: Nevertheless using a loop over each files in the above example could be adequate, right?